# Assets not showing when using expo:build for .apk after upgrading to SDK 39

Tags: react-native, expo

I am updating app from Expo SDK 38 to Expo SDK 39.  Everything goes smoothly it works perfectly in the Expo Client.

When I build a standalone app for testing before submission with the following:

```
expo build:android -t apk --release-channel some-build-release
```

I open the app to no assets showing.  My custom fonts which are in the same `assets` directory are being used properly.

I am bundling the assets directly into the binary with the following `app.json`:

```
"assetBundlePatterns": [
      "assets/**/*"
    ],
```

All of my assets are in the assets folder.  When I build a standalone app on SDK 38 everything works perfectly.  Assets show up with no issues.  Any help is appreciated.

The following is my `package.json` in case that helps:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
     ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "~1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "5.9.6",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "3.0.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.10.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.10.1",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.1",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.1",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.11.0",
    "@types/expo": "^32.0.13",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "convert-time": "^0.3.0",
    "expo": "^39.0.0",
    "expo-application": "~2.3.0",
    "expo-av": "~8.6.0",
    "expo-blur": "~8.2.0",
    "expo-camera": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-device": "~2.3.0",
    "expo-file-system": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-firebase-analytics": "~2.5.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-localization": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-location": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~9.2.1",
    "expo-network": "~2.3.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.7.2",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "expo-video-player": "^1.5.8",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-devtools": "^3.6.3",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.3.tar.gz",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-expo-image-cache": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-geocoding": "^0.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-keyboard-accessory": "^0.1.10",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.9.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.15.2",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.7",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^6.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "sentry-expo": "^3.0.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.1",
    "validator": "^12.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^3.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^3.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint": "^7.7.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.6",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.0.8",
    "typescript": "~3.9.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue?

Comment: @DomBarker See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was not an issue with the build process but instead an issue with another part of my code where other assets were getting saved to the `documentDirectory`.

I originally was saving assets (such as a small video) to the root `documentDirectory`.  I had another process that would clear old assets based on an array of values of "what should be there".

There was a change from Expo 38 -> 39 where binary assets now got bundled directly to the root of the `documentDirectory` so when my app was loading it would remove all the bundled assets.

Easy fix was to just store these other assets that I was loading on app launch to a subdirectory in the `documentDirectory` (in my case `documentDirectory/assetCache`).

Comment: thanks SKeney! Not my issue unfortunately